# Динамичный код javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать данный код динамичным, он просто только для одного чек бокса работает.

```
function logincheckboxCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked) {
        document.getElementById("checkboxDiv").className = "checkboxOn";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("checkboxDiv").className = "checkboxOff";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function logincheckboxCheck(el){
   if($(el).is(":checked")){
      $("#checkDiv").addClass("checkboxOn");
   }else{
      $("#checkDiv").addClass("checkboxOff");
   }
}
```

Тупо передаете элемент в функцию или:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="logincheckboxCheck(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function logincheckboxCheck(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
        el.className = "checkboxOn";
    } else {
        el.className = "checkboxOff";
    }
}
```

Лучше использовать другое событие, ведь можно не прямо по инпуту кликнуть, но и по label, который сделает чекбокс отмеченным

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="logincheckboxCheck(this)">
```